# Action Recognition for multiple objects and localization

Tags: machine-learning, classification, object-detection, activity-recognition

I want to ask question regarding the action detection on the video with proposed frames. I've used Temporal 3D ConvNet for the action recognition on video. Successfully trained it and can recognize action on videos.

When I do inference, I just collect 20 frames from video, feed it to model and it gives me the result. The point is that events on different videos are not similar size. Some of them cover 90% of the frame, but some may 10%. Let's take as an example that two objects collided and it can happen on a different scale, and I want to detect this action.

- How provide to the model exact position for action recognition, if it can happen on a different scale with different objects? What comes in mind is to use Yolo to collect Regions of Interest and feed collected frames every time the 3D convnet. But if there are a lot of objects, the speed will be very slow. How to handle it?
- Are there any end-to-end solutions for action recognition with the object location proposal for the action recognition network?

I've already looked at papers and blogs, what people suggest, couldn't find the solution for the localization issues, so action recognition model got correct frames.

So just for the summary, the idea is to get an object that can potentially collide in any scale and then feed for example 20 frames of it to 3D convnet to make the judgment.

Any advise from you? Maybe someone may explain me approach?

Answer (score 0):

This is my models CNN+LSTM, so currently trying to improve it.

```
    video = Input(shape=(None, 224,224,3))
cnn_base = VGG16(input_shape=(224,224,3),
                weights="imagenet",
                include_top=False)
cnn_out = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(cnn_base.output)
cnn = Model(inputs=cnn_base.input, outputs=cnn_out)
cnn.trainable = False
encoded_frames = TimeDistributed(cnn)(video)
encoded_sequence = LSTM(32, dropout=0.5, W_regularizer=l2(0.01), recurrent_dropout=0.5)(encoded_frames)
hidden_layer = Dense(units=64, activation="relu")(encoded_sequence)
dropout = Dropout(0.2)(hidden_layer)
outputs = Dense(5, activation="softmax")(dropout)
model = Model([video], outputs)
```